# Can I add a resistor to a 120V-24V power source to convert the amperage from 2.9 to 1.8?

Tags: resistors, amperage

I have an old Kodak printer dock for an Easyshare camera but I'm missing the power source for it. The dock requires 24V 1.8A power so I bought a power supply marked 24V (24.2 measured) and 70W but the printer only powers up and then shuts down after a few seconds. If the problem is the supply amperage is too high can I use a resistor inline somewhere to lower the amperage? As you may have guessed, I've done some research but I'm new to this kind of thing.

Comment: The problem is not the "amperage". There's something else wrong with the printer. Perhaps it needs to have the camera plugged into it.

Answer (score 4):

The printer dock determines how much current is drawn, you don't need to add a resistor.

Adding a resistor wouldn't help but if you play around with this, expect smoke, fire and burning shards embedded in both eyes - unless you use high-power resistors, probably lots in parallel.

70 W / 24 V = 2.9 A so the power supply should be able to supply 1.8 A without a problem.

Sometimes (often?) cheap power supplies are made or sold by people who basically lie about their products. I certainly have 9 V wall warts rated for 1 A whose voltage sags to 6 V when drawing 0.5 A.

I would

- Measure the voltage with a load on the power supply.
- Try a different power supply.

Comment: "basically lie" -> "lie".